# Iteratively extract repeated word forms across speaking turns

Tags: r, regex, for-loop

I'm working on speaking turns in conversation. My interest is in the words that get repeated from a prior turn to a next turn:

```
turnsX <- data.frame(
  speaker = c("A","B","A","B"),
  speech = c("let's have a look", 
             "yeah let's take a look",
             "yeah okay so where to start",
             "let's start here"), stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

I want to extract the repeated word forms. To this end I've run a `for` loop, iteratively defining each `speech` turn as a regex pattern for the next `speech` turn and `str_extract`ing the words that get repeated from turn to turn:

```
library(stringr)
pattern <- c()
extracted <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(turnsX)){
  pattern[i] <- paste0(unlist(str_split(turnsX$speech[i], " ")), collapse = "|")
  extracted[i+1] <- str_extract_all(turnsX$speech[i+1], pattern[i])
}
```

The result however is partly incorrect:

```
extracted
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] "a"     "let's" "a"     "a"     "look" 

[[3]]
[1] "yeah" "a"    "a"   

[[4]]
[1] "start"

[[5]]
[1] NA
```

The correct result should be:

```
extracted
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] "let's"    "a"     "look" 

[[3]]
[1] "yeah"   

[[4]]
[1] "start"
```

Where's the mistake? How can the code be mended, or what other approach is there, to get the correct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the word boundaries `"\\b"`

```
library(stringr)
pattern <- c()
extracted <- c()
for(i in 2:nrow(turnsX)){
  pattern[i - 1] <- paste0(unlist(str_split(turnsX$speech[i - 1], " ")), collapse = "|\\b")
  extracted[i] <- str_extract_all(turnsX$speech[i], pattern[i - 1])
}
# [[1]]
# NULL
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "let's" "a"     "look" 
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "yeah"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "start"
```

Comment: I've changed the pattern expression so that the `\\b`falls on either side of the words: `paste0("\\b(", paste0(unlist(str_split(kdd$Turn[i-1], " ")), collapse = "|"), ")\\b")`. In the larger dataset this does change the results quite a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use `Map` and `%in%`.

```
x <- strsplit(turnsX$speech, " ")
Map(function(y,z) y[y %in% z], x[-length(x)], x[-1])
#[[1]]
#[1] "let's" "a"     "look"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "yeah"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "start"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a base R approach using `Map` :

```
tmp <- strsplit(turnsX$speech, ' ')
c(NA, Map(intersect, tmp[-1], tmp[-length(tmp)]))

#[[1]]
#[1] NA

#[[2]]
#[1] "let's" "a"     "look" 

#[[3]]
#[1] "yeah"

#[[4]]
#[1] "start"
```

Comment: Very nice succint solution, thanks a lot. Any hint as to where my code is going wrong?

Comment: Couple of things I can suggest. 1) Your `for` loop goes from `1:nrow(turnsX)` it should be `1:(nrow(turnsX) - 1)` since for `nrow(turnsX)` there is no `i + 1` position. 2) Using regex makes this thing a bit more complicated than what it actually is. However, if you want to correct your approach you need to wrap `unique` in the `str_extract_all` output, initialise `extracted <- list()` and change last line to `extracted[[i]] <- unique(str_extract_all(turnsX$speech[i+1], pattern[i])[[1]])`

Comment: Sorry, you don't need `unique` you need word boundaries as shown in @jay.sf's solution.